Issues with NextJs 14.2 (app router) and global scss file
I am new to NextJs. I recently created a new project and was looking throught the documentation to see how to set it up correctly. There, I saw that I basically have a layout.tsx component that imports a global.css file, which is accessible throughout the application.
Since I've been using sass for a while now, I figured I would follow the steps to use it in my Next app. So I installed the npm package and changed my /src/app/global.css and /src/app/page.module.css files extensions to scss. After trying to set global variables I found they were not accessible in other pages.
I would get: SassError: Undefined variable $x
I thought that maybe this was related to the scoped nature of the .module.css files but after reverting back to the original state and creating css variables in global.css file:
:root {
  --x: #FFFFFF;
} 

I found they are accessible in other style files, for instance page.module.css:
.main {
  background-color: var(--x);
}

What am I missing here? I think the documentation is not clear in this regard and haven't been able to find solutions online.
Thanks for helping out!

Unlike CSS, SCSS variables need to be exported.
Next.js supports Sass variables exported from CSS Module files.
$x: #64ff00;
 
:export {
  myVariable: $x;
}

Then to use it:
import variables from './variables.module.scss'
 
export default function Page() {
  return <h1 style={{ color: variables.myVariable }}>Hello, Next.js!</h1>
}


Thank you for your answer! I get it, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of a global styles file? Also, in your example, wouldn't you have to have all styles pertaining to Page in the css file you declared the variable?

doesn't that defeat the purpose of a global styles file? somehow yes, but that's how it works in NextJs. wouldn't you have to have all styles pertaining to Page ... ? it's up to you how you want to manage your CSS files, my example is just for demonstration.

/* variables.module.css */

$x: #64ff00;
 
:export {
  myVariable: $x;
}

Usage in another CSS file
@import './variables.css';

.example {
  color: var(--myVariable);
}

Usage in JS file
import variables from './variables.module.scss'
 
export default function MyComponent() {
  return <h1 style={{ color: variables.myVariable }}>My Content</h1>
}

